# Displaying barcode on TextField with FXML controller

Tags: javafx

please I need help in displaying the generated barcode on the textField shown above. Here is my code I tried.

```
  @FXML 
  private void barcodePrev(ActionEvent event){
         if(imgPre !=null) 
                imgPre.clear();
         else
            imgPre = inputChar;
         System.out.print(imgPre);
  }
```

This code of mine isn't working; Sorry img removed due reputation.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `TextField.setText`??? The code snippet you posted is not really helpful btw, since basically all declarations are missing and doesn't really explain any where the input comes from and where you'd like the output to go.

Comment: Yes, like I said, the screen shot is removed. Every other thing is working perfectly. D problem is;  I have a text field named "inputChar" which accept  user data to be used for the barcode and I have another text field named imgPre which I want it to display the barcode generated As an output storage. And all this should happen when I trigger runCode button to create the image barcode.

Comment: Why use a `TextField` to display an barcode image instead of an `ImageView` or `Canvas` or similar node???

Comment: OK,  I need help with the implementation of any of the above two suggested, or even the two xo as to see which one works for me. Thanks